# Octave: Access value from a matrix by passing indices in a vector?

Tags: matlab, octave, linear-algebra

I need to access/edit values in an `n` dimensional matrix `M`, by passing a vector `V`, containing indices.

let
`M = [ 1,2,3;
       4,5,6;
       7,8,9;];`

index vectors be

`V1=[2,1];
 V2=[1,2];`

now,  `M(V1)` should give `4` 
 
and  `M(V2)` should give `2`;

problem is `n` is not fixed and I don't want do looping to access values like `M(idx_1,idx_2,...idx_n)`

Comment: use the [`sub2ind`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/sub2ind.html) function

Comment: using `sub2ind` is not enough if `n` really is not fixed. The trick to handle `n` without a for loop is to create a cell array which can then be used to create a comma separated list.

Comment: @Dan How do you pass a vector as argument in `sub2ind()` .ie `sub2ind([3,3],V1)` doesn't work. `v1=[2,1]`;

Comment: @shadowfox the only way is to convert it to a cell array and then to a comma separated list like in Carandraug's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many functions handle N dimensions by accepting a matrix with N columns. However, many others require you to pass N arguments instead. That is the case of [`sub2ind`](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Advanced-Indexing.html#index-sub2ind) (convert subscript indices into linear indices) which you need to solve your specific problem:

```
octave> M = randi (9, 3)
M =

   2   9   4
   5   9   5
   2   6   4

octave> ind = sub2ind (size (M), [2 1], [1 2]) # sub2ind (dims, rows, cols, 3rd_dim, 4th_dim, ...)
ind =

   2   4

octave> M(ind)
ans =

   5   9
```

The main trick to handle N dimensions is understanding [comma separated lists (cs-lists)](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Comma-Separated-Lists.html) and how you can [get them from cell arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Comma-Separated-Lists-Generated-from-Cell-Arrays.html). Using a 2D example like yours (but ignoring your `v1` and `v2` nonsense --- you should use a matrix `v` where each row is a point and each columns is a dimension), you can do:

```
octave> v = [2 1; 1 2];
octave> ind = sub2ind (size (M), num2cell (v, 1){:})
ind =

   2
   4

octave> M(ind)
ans =

   5
   9
```

The only thing that should need to be explained in the example above is:

```
octave> num2cell (v, 1) # returns a cell array
ans = 
{
  [1,1] =

     2
     1

  [1,2] =

     1
     2

}
octave> num2cell (v, 1){:} # transform the cell array into a cs-list
ans =

   2
   1

ans =

   1
   2
```

And you can use this to truly handle N dimensions:

```
octave> M = rand (9, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5);
octave> v = [5 5 5 5 5; 1 2 3 4 5; 3 2 4 4 1];
octave> ind = sub2ind (size (M), num2cell (v, 1){:});
octave> M(ind)
ans =

   0.13726
   0.14020
   0.78660

octave> [M(5, 5, 5, 5, 5); M(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); M(3, 2, 4, 4, 1)]
ans =

   0.13726
   0.14020
   0.78660
```